# the expressionType and includePath of CDT parser

Tags: testing, eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis

As we all know, we can retrieve the `ExpressionType` in certain cases. However, I am currently facing an issue where I need to retrieve the return type of functions like `scanf` and `printf`. I believe resolving the problem related to `includePath` in `IScannerInfo` could potentially solve this issue.

Unfortunately, I am encountering a lack of information regarding the CDT parser, which is hindering my progress. I am eager to find a solution.

Below is how I build the `ICPPTranslationUnit`. I have attempted to include the path to `stdio.h` in `includePaths`, but the `ExpressionType` of `scanf` remains `ProblemType`.

Additionally, it appears that the parser cannot recognize `size_t`. As a workaround, I have added it to `defineSymbols`, which seems to resolve the issue.

I appreciate any assistance or guidance on this matter. Thank you.

```
public ICPPASTTranslationUnit getASTTranslationUnit(String filePath) throws CoreException {
        FileContent fileContent = FileContent.createForExternalFileLocation(filePath);

        HashMap definedSymbols = new HashMap();
        definedSymbols.put("size_t", "unsigned");

        String path = "file path like stdio.h";
        String[] includePaths = {path};
        IScannerInfo info = new ScannerInfo(definedSymbols, includePaths);
        IParserLogService logger = new DefaultLogService();
        IncludeFileContentProvider emptyIncludes = IncludeFileContentProvider.getEmptyFilesProvider();

        int opts = ILanguage.OPTION_IS_SOURCE_UNIT;

        return (ICPPASTTranslationUnit) GPPLanguage.getDefault().getASTTranslationUnit(fileContent, info, emptyIncludes, null, opts, logger);
    }
```

Comment: My include path like belows, but it is not working.
```
        String[] includePaths = {
                "F:\\DevTools\\Dev-Cpp\\MinGW64\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\4.9.2\\include",
                "F:\\DevTools\\Dev-Cpp\\MinGW64\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\4.9.2\\include\\ssp"
        };
```